# package ‘dataset’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

Tags: r

I am installing different packages in R but I getting following error,even though I Installed Later Available R verson

Command:

```
install.packages("dataset")
```

Error:

```
package ‘dataset’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

Comment: It's `datasets` with an `s` on the end, but you shouldn't need to install it.  You should already have it as part of base R. See `library(help = "datasets")`

Comment: But I tried to Install other packages too like utils and grid with same error result?

Comment: look at `search()` These are all packages that don't usually need to be installed once R itself is installed.

Comment: what does search() do?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `datasets` package, with an `s`. That's pretty popular.

If not, the package you're looking for is probably in a different repository (not CRAN). You can install packages from other repositories with the `devtools` package. For example, if it's on GitHub you can type:

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_github("packageName")
```